# How Does Things 3 Tint their Status Bar Text

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Things 3 Screenshot]

In [Things 3](https://culturedcode.com/things/), the status bar text (wireless signal, time, battery, etc.) in the iOS app is a medium-gray color. Normally you can only have black or white text in the status bar.

**How are they doing this?**

My first guess is they have a semi-transparent white `UIView` covering the status bar, but I'm unsure how they pulled that off. I'd love to know how to do this in Swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some sample code in Swift that seems to mimic the Things 3 status bar effect pretty closely. In essence you're creating another window to place directly over the status bar that will mute the color slightly.

Important things to note in this example:

- We assign the new `UIWindow` to a property, otherwise it will be released as soon as we leave the scope.
- We set the `windowLevel` to `UIWindowLevelStatusBar`
- We set `isHidden` to `false` instead of calling `makeKeyAndVisible`, since we still want the normal window to be the key window

`AppDelegate.swift`:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var overlayWindow = UIWindow()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        overlayWindow.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 20)
        overlayWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
        overlayWindow.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.4)
        overlayWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        overlayWindow.isHidden = false

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great. Thank you! The only slight difference I see is that my battery icon is green, whereas Things managed to have a dark battery icon. I wonder how they pulled that off.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum The battery icon should only be green if you're plugged in to power, which also happens in Things implementation.

Comment: It looks like this doesn't handle orientation changes. Would I just have to listen for orientation change and then re-draw it?

Answer (score 1):

I expect they do it just as you say by adding a UIWindow over the status bar. Here is sample code that does it (in Objective-C.)

http://www.b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/multiple-uiwindows/

```
UIWindow* topWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
[topWindow setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelAlert];

CGFloat statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;

UIViewController* viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UIView* overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -statusBarHeight, viewController.view.frame.size.width, statusBarHeight - 1)];
[overlay setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[overlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
[viewController.view addSubview:overlay];
[topWindow setRootViewController:viewController];

[topWindow setHidden:NO];
[topWindow setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

[viewController release];
viewController = nil;

[overlay release];
overlay = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. This seems pretty close to the accepted answer.