# iOS 13 Status Bar Text Color

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to overlay the status bar text to make it different from the default black/white.

I know it was possible before and I was using solution with UIWindow, with
`overlayWindow.windowLevel = .statusBar` (trying to get above this value don't help either) [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44251422/how-does-things-3-tint-their-status-bar-text)

I also found ways to get the `statusBarView` but this only allows to set the background color. [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651245/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-13)

What's more; Things3 app before managed to get the status bar text color to gray but now on iOS13 it appears black.

If You know any valid hacks for this would love to hear about them!

Comment: Have you checked your testing device is not in `dark mode`?

Comment: Yup, and trying both on simulator and physical device. Also disabling the dark mode in plist÷.